# Trying to get property of non-objec

Tags: php

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://quest7.myddt.com.br/serverlist.ashx');

echo $xml->Result->Item->Port;

//echo '<pre>';
//var_dump($xml);
```

> **error :** Trying to get property of non-object  what fix ?

Comment: from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) *"Returns an object of class SimpleXMLElement with properties containing the data held within the XML document, **or FALSE on failure**."* what did your `var_dump` say?

Comment: also if `$xml` is coming back as an object make sure you accessing the data correctly. according to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) you access attributes of an element just as you would elements of an array.

Comment: @Memor-X what ?

Comment: first off your not even checking if `simplexml_load_file` has returned false which is one way your error occurs. another way is that from the page i [linked to](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) it says that attributes of an element is are accessed like elements of an array and you see an example of this. when i load the link i see `Port` as an attribute. for the most part your `var_dump` should be giving you valuable information of what is wrong so you need to share what it outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root element is loaded, so you skip `Result` and then `Port` is an attribute of `Item` so you reference it like an array index:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://quest7.myddt.com.br/serverlist.ashx');

if ($xml !== false){
    echo $xml->Item['Port'];
} else {
    echo "something went wrong...";
}
```

> 8000

Comment: Problem is that the same error can still occur if `simplexml_load_file` returns false which is what i'm getting [here](https://repl.it/Dn73) (though might just be my connection). ideally you should be checking that `$xml` isn't false first before trying to use it as an object

Comment: @Memor-X fair enough - I've updated my answer, thanks!